# Python beautifulsoup looping through span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code below returns a load of span results, how do i loop through each span (there's like 6 of them, see one example below) to extract 'data-stock'? I noticed there is no span class hence why I am stuck on how to loop this.

Many thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.smythstoys.com/uk/en-gb/video-games-and-tablets/playstation-5/playstation-5-games/sackboy-a-big-adventure-ps5/p/191447"
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
               'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

    gear = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'instoreMessage')
    print(gear)
```

Produces:

[

Available only in store.

```
<span data-channel="CLICK_AND_COLLECT" data-location="" data-stock="PREORDER" style="display:none">
    
    
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="check_i" valign="top" width="3%"><i class="fa fa-check green-check"></i></td>
                    <td>Smyths <a data-target="#price-promise-mdl" data-toggle="modal" style="cursor: pointer;">Pre-order Price Promise</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
    
</span>
```

[/div]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `gear` elements (there's only one), find all the `<span>` tags. Then just iterate through that list and grab the `data-stock` attribute:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.smythstoys.com/uk/en-gb/video-games-and-tablets/playstation-5/playstation-5-games/sackboy-a-big-adventure-ps5/p/191447"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

gear = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'instoreMessage')
print(gear)

spans = gear[0].find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    print (span['data-stock'])
```

**Output:**

```
CCUNAVAILABLEONLYPREORDER
PREORDER
PREORDER
PREORDER
PREORDER
INSTOCK
INSTOCK
```

Comment: hey many thanks! made it look so easy, sorry i come from VBA so this is all new to me!

Comment: no worries! I remember learning all this stuff (and still learning). It's fun! Just keep at it, keep practicing...it get's easier.